# Cannot allow IPv4 PING on 'private' network, but disabling firewall works - issue with Hyper-V?

Tags: ping, hyper-v

Windows 10 Enterprise on a Lenovo ThinkStation P520 tower. I ran this command, but it does nothing:

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow`

The NIC *was* the Hyper-V vSwitch NIC, but I recreated it, per: https://serverfault.com/questions/827181/hyper-v-not-able-to-ping-my-local-vm-from-host

Ping still fails with the Windows firewall on, so I just deleted the vSwitch, stopped Hyper-V on the machine and rebooted - no change.

Comment: Try the older format of the command : `netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8`.

Comment: Thanks, @harrymc. Tried it - still no joy